# Word like "serendipity" but with less emphasis on fortune or development of events

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say that the previous week I bumped into a lot of people I knew as a child. Each event was random, occurred independently of the other and all were unconnected except that each of the people involved knew each other at around the same time that I knew them.

*Serendipity* seems a bit too strong a word for this because I gained no fortune and there was no chain of dependence in the events. *Coincidence* doesn't really fit, either.

There must be a word for this - or a way to explain it concisely. What is it?

Comment: Why doesn't *coincidence* fit?

Comment: It doesn't seem right. I'm a native English speaker and to me a coincidence would be bumping into the same person twice in different circumstances - this is a bit like a cluster coincidence. There must be a better word.

Comment: I don't think there is a single word to describe this. Perhaps just a "series of coincidences"?

Comment: I think you just use the word too narrowly. An applicable definition of *coincidence*: *a chance occurrence of events remarkable either for being simultaneous or for apparently being connected* (via dictionary.com)

Comment: Though if you're really opposed to it, you could always go with *fluke*.

Comment: A Series of [Un]fortunate Events?

Answer (score 6):

[Synchronicity](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/synchronicity) is the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly isn’t *serendipity*. If you want an alternative to *coinicidence*, you might think about *fortuity*, but *a series of coincidences* seems to describe the events adequately.

Comment: +1: I was going to answer *fortuitous/fortuity*.  The only concern there, however, is that many people see fortu- and equate fortuitous with fortunate.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried "Happenstance"?